# Search nested array of objects and return full parents as results in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've successfully written a recursive function to loop through a nested object and find the results. But I'm having a hard time adding the entire parent if its children pass the test. I have the following code:

```js
const myObj = [
  {
    name: '1',
    pages: [
      {
        name: '1.1',
        pages: []
      },
      {
        name: '1.2',
        pages: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    pages: []
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    pages: []
  }
]

function searchPages(searchQuery, obj) {
  let searchResults = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    let item = searchString(obj[i], searchQuery);

    if (item) {
      searchResults.push(item);
    }
  }
  return searchResults;
}

function searchString(obj, string) {
  if (obj.name.includes(string)) {
    return obj;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.pages.length; i++) {
    const possibleResult = searchString(obj.pages[i], string);
    if (possibleResult) {
      return possibleResult;
    }
  }
}

let searchResults = searchPages('1.1', myObj);
console.log(searchResults);
```

This searches the nested array properly and gives the correct result:

```
  {
    "name": "1.1",
    "pages": []
  }
```

But I would like to return the entire parent object, instead of just the child object. So the expected result is this:

```
  {
    name: '1',
    pages: [
      {
        name: '1.1',
        pages: []
      },
      {
        name: '1.2',
        pages: []
      },
    ]
  }
```

How can I modify my function to achieve this?

Keep in mind this is just a small object just for readability purposes. My actual object will have many more levels and properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and check if the nested arrays have the wanted name.

```js
function searchPages(array, string) {
    const find = ({ name, pages }) => name.includes(string) || pages && pages.some(find);
    return array.filter(find);
}

const
    data = [{ name: '1', pages: [{ name: '1.1', pages: [] }, { name: '1.2', pages: [] }] }, { name: '2', pages: [] }, { name: '3', pages: [] }],
    searchResults = searchPages(data, '1.1');

console.log(searchResults);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! seems to work for me, but is there a way to modify this so it includes partial strings? like what i did in my function `obj.name.includes(string)`

Comment: you can replace the check with `includes`. please see edit.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return the parent `object` instead of the searched `object`, you just need to change the `searchString()` implementation so it takes the parent as third param, and then return it if you find the desired `string`:

```
function searchPages(searchQuery, obj) {
  let searchResults = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    let item = searchString(obj[i], searchQuery, obj);

    if (item) {
      searchResults.push(item);
    }
  }
  return searchResults;
}

function searchString(obj, string, parent) {
  if (obj.name.includes(string)) {
    return parent;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.pages.length; i++) {
    const possibleResult = searchString(obj.pages[i], string, obj);
    if (possibleResult) {
      return possibleResult;
    }
  }
}
```

This way you will always take the parent into account.

**Demo:**

```js
const myObj = [
  {
    name: '1',
    pages: [
      {
        name: '1.1',
        pages: [
          {
            name: '1.1.1',
            pages: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: '1.2',
        pages: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    pages: []
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    pages: []
  }
]

function searchPages(searchQuery, obj) {
  let searchResults = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    let item = searchString(obj[i], searchQuery, obj);

    if (item) {
      searchResults.push(item);
    }
  }
  return searchResults;
}

function searchString(obj, string, parent) {
  if (obj.name.includes(string)) {
    return parent;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.pages.length; i++) {
    const possibleResult = searchString(obj.pages[i], string, obj);
    if (possibleResult) {
      return possibleResult;
    }
  }
}

let searchResults = searchPages('1.1.1', myObj);
console.log(searchResults);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but this doesnt work with arrays nested more than 2 levels

Comment: @cup_of can you reproduce it with an example?

Comment: yeah ive edited your answer, it will only return its immediate parent

Comment: @cup_of because this is the parent, you said you need to return the parent and not the current object.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach with `.filter`-ing `myObj` and `.find`-ing nested pages with given name

```js
const myObj = [
  {
    name: '1',
    pages: [
      {
        name: '1.1',
        pages: []
      },
      {
        name: '1.2',
        pages: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    pages: []
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    pages: []
  }
];

const searchPages = (name, arr) => arr.filter(
  ({ pages }) => pages.find(page => page.name === name)
) 

let searchResults = searchPages('1.1', myObj);
console.log(searchResults);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible approach, using `.filter` for the top array, followed by recursive calls of `.some`:

```js
const myObj = [
  {
    name: '1',
    pages: [
      {
        name: '1.1',
        pages: []
      },
      {
        name: '1.2',
        pages: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '2',
    pages: []
  },
  {
    name: '3',
    pages: []
  }
];

const searchPages = (nameToFind, obj) => obj.filter(pageContainsName(nameToFind));
const pageContainsName = nameToFind => ({ name, pages }) => (
  name === nameToFind || pages.some(pageContainsName(nameToFind))
);
let searchResults = searchPages('1.1', myObj);
console.log(searchResults);
```